# Are deleted email accounts made available for re-use in Tutanota?

Tags: email, account-security

When deleting an account, [Tutanota](https://tutanota.com/) shows this message:

> Do you really want to delete your account? Your email addresses can be
>   taken over by the account [email]@tutanota.com.

Does Tutanota allow creating an account using deleted Tutanota email address?

Comment: This seems like a very simple question. Is there any reason you think that Tutanota would not allow this?

Comment: I have misunderstood, Tutanota **doesn't** make deleted email addresses available again: https://tutanota.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/547633-do-you-delete-inactive-accounts-recycle-email-ad

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Someone else can intercept any future messages sent to that address you deleted.

I assume they could not see past emails as those would be deleted.

However, emails that arrive some in the future could be accessed after you delete that address and another person decides they want to take it over.

Disclaimer: I have no knowledge of Tutanota. I am just explaining the logical meaning of the text you have posted.

Comment: I must have misunderstood, Tutanota **doesn't** make deleted email addresses available again: https://tutanota.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/547633-do-you-delete-inactive-accounts-recycle-email-ad